# nginx startup creates orphan process

Tags: linux, bash, nginx

It seems that the nginx webserver startup works as follows

1. Command like "/bin/nginx -c ~/nginx.conf" creates a process with PID X
2. Process with PID X creates the nginx master process and immediately terminates
3. The nginx master process creates the worker and other auxiliary processes and is ready to serve requests

Since the PID X that created nginx master process is terminated, the PPID of nginx master process is 1 and its an orphan. My question is- is there a way to avoid this orphaning? Specifically, can I avoid the creation of this PID X in step 1 and directly create the nginx master process?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). This page is dedicated to questions about software development.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out- the step 2 occurs because daemon feature in nginx is ON by default. Turn it off and it would simply start the nginx master process- https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#daemon